# system error '-2147024773 (8007007b)' the filename,directoryname or volumelabel syntax is incorrect when i click on macro button

Tags: excel, vba

y i get  system error &h800700b (-2147024773) filename,directoryname or volumelabelsyntax is 
 incorrect.help me to find out what exactly this error is.

```
Save the PDF file
reportSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="D:\slipdata\" & SName, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of ```SName```? That error is for invalid names.

Comment: value of sname is 
SName = Application.Proper(detailsSheet.Cells(i, 2))

Comment: Whats in that cell then? ```debug.print``` the value.